# Checkbox functionality in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to build an application in `VueJS` where I'm having some `checkbox` that gets `selected` on clicking.

My UI looks like this:

[image]

If we try to `select/de-select` `individual` `checkbox` it is working fine. If we `check/uncheck` via the `select all` button it working perfectly fine. But when we select all and try to `uncheck` with the `individual` `checkbox` it is `slicing` the actual `checkbox` list

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the above image I tried unchecking the RTY option and it got removed from the child component's `variables` array

My Concept:

I'm having a `parent` element where I'm passing the selections as `props` to this `checkbox` element:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <selection-component :selected_fields="selected_fields"></selection-component>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import selectionComponent from './../selection-component'
import {eventBus} from "../../../../../models/_events";

export default {
    name: "MainLayout",
    components: {
      selectionComponent
    },

    data(){
        return{
            selected_fields:{},
        }
    },
    created() {
        //Fetch selections via API (axios) call
        
        //capturing events from child components (selection-component)
        
        eventBus.$on('admin_watercraft_filter', (data) => {
            if(typeof data.var_name !== 'undefined') {
                if(typeof data.data !== 'undefined' && data.data!=='' && data.data.length!==0)
                    this.selected_fields[data.var_name] = data.data;
                else if(typeof this.selected_fields[data.var_name] !== 'undefined' || data.data === '' || data.data.length===0 )
                    delete this.selected_fields[data.var_name];
            }
            else  this.selected_fields = data;

            console.log(this.selected_fields);
        });

        eventBus.$on('admin_watercraft_create', (data) => {
            if(typeof this.selected_fields[data.var_name] === 'undefined') {
                this.selected_fields[data.var_name] = [];
                this.selected_fields[data.var_name].push(data.data);
            }
            else this.selected_fields[data.var_name].push(data.data);
        });

        eventBus.$on('admin_watercraft_remove', (data) => {

            var index = _.findIndex(this.selected_fields[data.var_name], (q) => {
                return q.id === data.data.id
            })
            if(index > -1) this.selected_fields[data.var_name].splice(index, 1);
        });



    }
}
</script>
```

And I have `child` component `selection-component` as:

```
<template>
    <div class="mt-3 lg:mt-0">
        <div class="flex justify-between items-center mb-3">
            <div class="flex items-center">
                <input @click="selectAll($event)" :checked="selectAllChecked" type="checkbox" class="h-6 w-6 rounded-md bg-gray-200 border-none">
                <div class="ml-2">
                    <div class="text-sm font-normal">Select Checkbox</div>
                    <div class="font-extralight text-gray-400" style="font-size: 11px">Assign by checking</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex">
                <div class="h-8 rounded-l-lg w-8 bg-gray-100 flex">
                    <div class="m-auto text-sm font-semibold ">$</div>
                </div>
                <input v-model="price" style="width: 70px" class="h-8 px-2 text-sm font-normal rounded-r-lg border focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-400">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <input v-model="search" type="search" class="text-sm font-normal px-4 py-2 my-3 border-none rounded-xl w-full bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-200" placeholder="Search...">
            <div class="overflow-y-auto h-40">
                <div v-for="(ele, index) in tableData" class="flex items-center justify-between my-1 pr-3">
                    <div class="flex items-center">
                        <input :value="ele.id" @click="selectData(ele, $event)" :checked="ele.selected" type="checkbox" class="h-6 w-6 rounded-md bg-gray-200 border-none">
                        <div class="text-xs font-normal ml-2">{{ele.name}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex">
                        <div class="h-8 rounded-l-lg w-10 bg-gray-100 flex">
                            <div class="m-auto text-sm font-semibold ">$</div>
                        </div>
                        <input v-model="ele.price" style="width: 75px" class="h-8 px-4 text-sm font-normal rounded-r-lg border focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-400">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import {eventBus} from "../../../../../models/_events";

export default {
    name: "SelectionComponent",
    props:['selected_fields'],
    data(){
        return{
            variables: [
                {id:1, name:'ABC', price:''},
                {id:2, name:'QWE', price:''},
                {id:3, name:'RTY', price:''},
            ],
           var_name:'source_file',
           price:''
        
        }
    },
    methods:{
        selectData(ele, event) {
            const dataset = {
                var_name: this.var_name,
                data: ele
            }
            if(event.target.checked) eventBus.$emit('admin_watercraft_create', dataset);
            else eventBus.$emit('admin_watercraft_remove', dataset);
        },
        selectAll(event) {
            let dataSet
            if(event.target.checked) dataSet = {var_name: this.var_name, data: this.variables}
            else dataSet = {var_name: this.var_name, data: []}

            eventBus.$emit("admin_watercraft_filter", dataSet);
        },
        checked(element){
            if(typeof this.selected_fields[this.var_name] === 'undefined') return false;
            return this.selected_fields[this.var_name].some(el => el.id === element.id);
        },
    },
    computed: {
        tableData() {
            if (typeof this.variables !== 'undefined' && this.variables.length) {
                return this.variables.map(a => ({
                    name: a.name,
                    id: a.id,
                    price: a.price,
                    selected: this.checked(a)
                }))
            }
        },
        selectAllChecked(){
            if(typeof this.selected_fields[this.var_name] === 'undefined') return false;
            return this.variables.length === this.selected_fields[this.var_name].length
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

don't know why it is `splicing` the actual `variable` inside the `child` component. I need to keep the `state` of `variables` array defined inside the child component.